# Hibernate audit trail aganist user action?

Tags: hibernate, audit-trail

we have requiremnet to log each user action and fields modifeid due to this action. Audit logging is implemented using the hibernate interceptor

Inorder to get the user action in the hibernate interceptor what would be the best approch

Comment: So, have you read upon [Hibernate interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html)? What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: Yes i have already implemented the hibernate interceptor and able to compare the old and new values. But the problem is get GUI action details(process which intiated the request) in the interceptor.

Comment: So how are we supposed to help you if you are not providing any details? How can we know anything about your GUI layer?